# How to make an array list of arrays [JAVA]

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am making a code where I need an ArrayList of 5 Arrays, 4 of String type and 1 of boolean type.

So... could you help me making just getter and setter of this?

It's all I need, I would thank you a lot

I'm using Input and Output Files and Streams (I'm starting using Java 'cause I'm a student, so I know just a couple of things).

I have this piece of code

```
//This belongs to the class where I want to read file written in myClass
ArrayList<myClass> myArrayList = new ArrayList<myClass>();

//This is into myClass class
String code[] = new String[200];
String meaning[] = new String[200];
String text1[] = new String[200];
String text2[] = new String[200];
boolean add[] = new boolean[200];

//I read myFile.txt in any class
try{
    ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("myFile.txt"));
    myArrayList = (ArrayList<myClass>)in.readObject();
    in.close();
}
catch(Exception e){
}
```

So, how could I read and write this arrayList on the file, with those getter and setter?

I still can't figure it out and I have a week thinking about it.

Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You could  use non generic array list.

```
ArrayList arr =new ArrayList()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    public static void  main(String []args)


{
  ArrayList  arr=new ArrayList();
  String str[]=new String[20];
  Integer in[]=new Integer[20];
  arr.add(in);
  arr.add(str);
```

}
ArrayList of type object means its Generic type can accept any type of object.
But when reading the arraylist we need to typecast to the corresponding datatype.